# How to Upgrade to Ruby 3 with Pacemaker Installed?

Tags: ruby, cluster-computing, high-availability, pacemaker, rocky-os

We have pacemaker (pcs) installed on Rocky8. When upgrading to Ruby 3.1, it is not able to install while the Ruby 2.5 exists which was instlled and run with pacemaker.

How should we do to upgrade Ruby to the newer version with pacemaker installed?

Thank you for everyone's help.

We are meeting the below errors:

Error:

```
Problem 1: cannot install both ruby-libs-3.1.2-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743.x86_64 and ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64

- package pcs-0.10.14-5.el8_7.2.x86_64 requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install the best update candidate for package ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64
- cannot install the best update candidate for package pcs-0.10.14-5.el8_7.2.x86_64
- package ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  Problem 2: cannot install both ruby-libs-3.1.2-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743.x86_64 and ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64
- package ruby-augeas-0.5.0-24.el8.x86_64 requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package ruby-3.1.2-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743.x86_64 requires libruby.so.3.1()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package ruby-3.1.2-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743.x86_64 requires ruby-libs(x86-64) = 3.1.2-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743, but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install the best update candidate for package ruby-augeas-0.5.0-24.el8.x86_64
- cannot install the best update candidate for package ruby-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64
- package ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  Problem 3: problem with installed package ruby-augeas-0.5.0-24.el8.x86_64
- package ruby-augeas-0.5.0-24.el8.x86_64 requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both ruby-libs-3.1.2-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743.x86_64 and ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64
- package rubygem-bigdecimal-3.1.1-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743.x86_64 requires libruby.so.3.1()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install the best update candidate for package rubygem-bigdecimal-1.3.4-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64
- package ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  Problem 4: problem with installed package pcs-0.10.14-5.el8_7.2.x86_64
- package pcs-0.10.14-5.el8_7.2.x86_64 requires libruby.so.2.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both ruby-libs-3.1.2-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743.x86_64 and ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64
- package rubygem-io-console-0.5.11-141.module+el8.7.0+1081+f0a69743.x86_64 requires libruby.so.3.1()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install the best update candidate for package rubygem-io-console-0.4.6-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64
- package ruby-libs-2.5.9-110.module+el8.6.0+992+fc951c18.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  (try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```